# Заголовок host при запросе на нестандартный порт

Tags: http

При запросе к серверу должен ли в заголовок `host` включаться номер порта?

Похоже, Download Master шлёт такой запрос:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Download Master
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Host: localhost
```

И до моего обработчика на nodejs он не доходит.

Если дописать в заголовок `host` номер порта, то всё работает:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Download Master
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Host: localhost:8080
```

Если убрать заголовок `host`, то всё тоже работает.

Насколько я понимаю, убирать неправильно - он должен присутствовать.
А вот по поводу наличия номера порта - должен ли он там быть?

---

Как оказалось, Download Master вообще шлёт запрос по относительному url на порт 8080:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Download Master
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost
```

Comment: Возьми все свои 13К в правую руку и резким движением реши свою проблему :)))
А мне на эти рейтинги пофигу, родной. Кю!

Comment: включите вайршарк и посмотрите, что у вас там реально уходит, чтобы на кофейной гуще не гадать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Современный (на 05.01.2016) протокол HTTP описан в [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230).

Выдержки из п. 5.4, описывающего заголовок `HOST`, данного стандарта:

> 1. Клиент ДОЛЖЕН посылать заголовок Host во всех запросах HTTP/1.1
>    2. Если URI содержит authority component клиент ДОЛЖЕН послать значение Host идентичное authority component, за исключением имени пользователя (отделенного @).
>    3.  Сервер ДОЛЖЕН ответить кодом 400 (Bad Request) на любой HTTP/1.1 запрос с отсутствующим или неверным заголовком Host.

П. 2.7.1 описывает *authority component* как состоящий из *имени хоста* И, опционально, TCP порта ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3)).

Далее в п. 2.7.1 есть фраза:

> Если порт пустой или не задан, TCP порт 80 (зарезервирован для WWW) используется по умолчанию.

Таким образом, Download Master нарушает стандарт HTTP, указывая в заголовке Host значение, отличное от *authority component* указанного в URI (т.е. без номера порта, при том, что в URI он его указал). На что сервер *должен* ответить ему отказом с кодом 400.

Замечу, что стандарт на протокол HTTP/1.0 был менее требовательный и разрешал запросы HTTP *без* заголовка `HOST`. Следуя этому большинство web-серверов на всякий случай разрешают запросы без заголовка `HOST` и для HTTP/1.1 (что в принципе не соответствует стандарту 1.1)

**Итого**: Да, в заголовке Host порт, отличный от 80, должен присутствовать, т.к. согласно п 2.7.1 стандарта отсутствие порта в URI подразумевает порт 80 и согласно п. 5.4 Host должен содержать такое же определение сервера назначения как в URI.

Comment: Оказалось, что в uri он тоже не указывает. Просто открывает соединение на порт 8080, шлёт запрос на относительный uri и не прописывает в хосте порт.

Comment: Ну это он конечно большой молодец, ни через какой прозрачный прокси не пройдет. Ну и Node видимо проверяет где то. правда я пытался эту проверку в исходниках node найти, но не нашел

Comment: http://downloadmaster.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30606 - посмотрим, что скажут.

Comment: Ой.. Хм.. Похоже, проверку не node делает, а кто-то ещё. Именно для порта 8080. При 8081 запрос обрабатывается корректно. А при 8080 не приходит.

Answer (score 1):

Перевод секции 5.2 [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.2):

> 1. Если Request-URI - это absoluteURI, то хост - это часть
>        Request-URI. Любое значение поля заголовка Host в запросе
>        ДОЛЖНО игнорироваться.
> 2. Если Request-URI - не absoluteURI, а запрос содержит поле
>        заголовка Host, то хост определяется значением поля
>        заголовка Host.
> 3. Если хоста, определенного правилами 1 или 2 не существует на
>        сервере, код состояния ответа ДОЛЖЕН быть 400 (Bad Request).

То есть в зависимости от вида URI `host` может игнорироваться. В самом `host` порт необязателен; если порт не указан, то по умолчанию 80-й. Весь вопрос в том, какой у вас URI и как его обрабатывает сервер.

Хотя из того что вы написали похоже что если присутствует заголовок `host`, ваш сервер по возможности старается использовать его, игнорируя стандарт (ну или я совсем не понимаю отличия абсолютного URI от относительного).

В целом наверно стоит всегда добавлять заголовок `host` (черт его знает, что разработчикам сервера в голову ударит), и везде хост должен быть одинаковым (никак не могу придумать ситуацию, когда это должно быть не так).

Comment: Вообще в п. 14.23 RFC сказано что HTTP1/1 сервера _ДОЛЖНЫ_ отвечать 400 bad request на отсутствующий host. Так что просто всем везет, что все сервера поддерживают HTTP1/0 и не обращают внимания на эту рекомендацию RFC и для 1.1.

Answer (score -4):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14

Host = "Host" ":" host [ ":" port ] ; Section 3.2.2

Т.е. порт является опциональным. Как правило, если не указан явно, браузеры его и не добавляют. Нажмите в браузере F12 и посмотрите сами.
Но! Как обрабатывать запрос, зависит от сервера. Сервер может игнорировать вообще номер порта и обрабатывать все запросы как HTTP или делать с ними, что нравится. Это его личные предпочтения.
Скажите вашему серверу принимать запросы в том числе и по 80-му порту по дефолту и настанет щастье.

Comment: Но ведь порт и в самом запросе является опциональным и http по умолчанию меппится на 80й. Означает ли наличие нестандартного порта в запросе, что этот порт также должен присутствовать в `host`е? Или они не обязаны быть консистентными?

Comment: Давайте так :)
При сетевом взаимодействии используется пара: IP:PORT<->IP:PORT
Но, HTTP работает поверх TCP/IP. 
При этом запрос на порт и HTTP-заголовок не обязаны совпадать.
И ваш сервер слушает порты, а что указано в заголовках HTTP - вторично.
Поэтому танцуйте от сервера и смотрите на каком порту он принимает соединение. А потом смотрите, как он фильтрует заголовки.

Comment: А если не так, а по спецификации?

Comment: Вам ссылки на RFC дать?
По RFC я вам и объяснил. Дальше разбирайтесь с вашими настройками вашего ПО.

Comment: Есть два места, в которых порт необязателен. Вопрос: должны ли эти два места быть в консистентном состоянии или нет? Ответа на него я не вижу.

Comment: В 3.2.2 говорится "If the port is empty or not given, port 80 is assumed." - это следует понимать, что если в `host` не указан порт, то предполагается 80?

Comment: Есть одно место где порт обязателен, это TCP. Ваш запрос приходит на определенный TCP-порт. И это никак не связано с HTTP заголовками. 
Если эта концепция непонятна, почитайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI

Поверх TCP идет текстовый HTTP файл.содержимое которого может быть любым. И с этим содержимым разбирается HTTP-сервер. Или любой другой сервер, слушающий порт, на который пришел запрос.
Поэтому, смотрите логи и разбирайтесь с настройками вашего сервера.

Comment: Если содержимое любое, то оно не является валидным. Вопрос задан вполне конкретный и не надо вместо ответа объяснять, как работает http.

Comment: На конкретный вопрос был дан более чем конкретный ответ.
При запросе к серверу должен ли в заголовок host включаться номер порта?
Host = "Host" ":" host [ ":" port ] - порт отционален.

Comment: Я вообще-то свои 13К рейтинга заработал. Так что лучше думать перед тем как говорить.

Comment: @Qwertiy Не понимаю, почему все отвечающие на вопрос ссылаются только на 3.2.2. В п. 14.23 того же RFC явно сказано _A "host" without any trailing port information implies the default port for the service requested (80)_ Я бы понял эту фразу так, что порт отличный от 80 должен присутствовать. Хотя конечно не указанный на этот случай _MUST_ - просчет стандарта.

Comment: @Mike, предлагаю написать ответом.